# removeAt() in Angular Form always deletes the first value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I noticed when I delete an element from my `FormArray` it always deletes the first entry rather than the index being passed into it.  Even stranger, when I console.log the value being passed into my function which should be of type `number` I get an entire `FormControl` object which I can't understand how or why that's happening.

Overall I'm creating an SVG parser and am working on a form for the user to edit and or modify before saving it to the database after the SVG has been parsed and shaped into a data object.  I want the user to be able to add or remove fields for attributes and styles so I have a mechanism that looks like this

***AttributeListComponent.ts***

```
export class AttributeListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() AttributeListData: FormArray;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    //this.showData();
  }

  showData(){ console.log(this.AttributeListData); }


  addAttribute(): void{
    const newAttribute: FormGroup = CreateAttributeForm();
    let attrList: FormArray = <FormArray>this.AttributeListData as FormArray;
    //console.log(newAttribute);
    attrList.push(newAttribute);
    //this.showData();
  }

  deleteAttribute(item: number): void{
    let attrList:FormArray = this.AttributeListData as FormArray;

    console.log(item);

    attrList.removeAt(item);

    //this.AttributeListData.removeAt(item);
  }

}
```

***AttributeListComponent.html***

```
<section>

    <article *ngIf="!AttributeListData">
        <p>loading</p>
    </article>

    <article *ngIf="AttributeListData">

        <h5 *ngIf="AttributeListData.controls.length === 0">no attributes</h5>

        <section *ngIf="AttributeListData.controls.length > 0">


            <article *ngFor="let item of AttributeListData.controls; let i of index">

                <attribute-form-component  [AttributeFormData]="item"></attribute-form-component>
                <button (click)="deleteAttribute(i)">delete</button>

            </article>


        </section>

    </article>

    <article>
        <button (click)="addAttribute()">add</button>
    </article>

</section>
```

***AttributeFormComponent.ts***

```
export class AttributeFormComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() AttributeFormData: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

***AttrbuteFormComponent.html***

```
<article>
    <label for="attribute">
        <input
            type="text"
            name="attribute"
            id="attribute"
            [value]="AttributeFormData.controls.attribute.value[0]"
            formControlName="attribute"
        />
    </label>

    <label for="setting">
        <input
            type="text"
            name="setting"
            id="setting"
            [value]="AttributeFormData.controls.setting.value[0]"
            formControlName="setting"
        />
    </label>
</article>
```

Seeing that the overall mechanism is so dynamic by nature I decided to create separate functions for creating different parts of the form which is what the `CreateAttributeForm()` comes into play in the `AttributeListComponent` which looks like this.

***CreateAttributeForm***

```
export function CreateAttributeForm(data?: OvaadGraphicAttribute): FormGroup{
    return new FormGroup({
      attribute: new FormControl([(data ? data.attribute : ''), Validators.required]),
      setting:   new FormControl([(data ? data.setting : ''), Validators.required])
    }) as FormGroup;
  }
```

Now if we look at my `deleteAttribute()` function below, the `console.log()` somehow returns an entire `FormGroup` object.

```
deleteAttribute(item: number): void{
    let attrList:FormArray = this.AttributeListData as FormArray;

    console.log(item);

    attrList.removeAt(item);

    //this.AttributeListData.removeAt(item);
  }
```

I even changed it to `console.log(item.controls)` and even though VSCode threw its own internal error telling me

> Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'number'.ts(2339)

it still logged out the controls for for the FormGroup, so I really don't understand how or why this is happening especially with `item:number` while not throwing a type error.  Can anybody spot anything I'm doing wrong?  I haven't gotten around to using the `ControlValueAccessor` or anything yet to update the values in the parent form and was wondering if maybe that has something to do with it because I honestly can't find anything pointing at something extra we need to do in order to delete the proper item. Everything just shows `let i of index` and `ourDeleteItemFunction(i)` as a click event.

Comment: I think it should be `index as i` in the short form, like this `<article *ngFor="let item of AttributeListData.controls; index as i">`

Comment: that gives the error
***Can't bind to 'ngForAs' since it isn't a known property of 'article'.***

Comment: That's weird, what version of angular are you using? .. btw [Angular API - ngForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

Answer (score 0):

ok I just found the problem.  The `ngFor` condition should have `let i = index` when I have `let i of index`. so it should look like this

```
<article *ngFor="let item of AttributeListData.controls; let i = index">
...
</article>
```

It still doesn't explain how a `FormObject` was able to be passed to an argument of type `number` but it works now :)

Comment: Why would not pass .. There is no type check at runtime .. Is JavaScript .. You could pass whatever you want .. Although there are alternative libraries if you actually want to have type check at runtime